# Ordered Sets and Lattices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Recall the topic “Ordered sets and Lattices” that the set $D_m$ of divisors of $m$ is a bounded, distributive lattice with 
$$a+b = a\lor b =\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)$$
$$ab = a\land b =\gcd(a, b)$$

(a) Show that $D_m$ is a Boolean algebra if $m$ is square free, i.e., if $m$ is a product of distinct primes.
(b) Find the atoms of $D_m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the divisors of m area bounded, distributive lattice, all that is left to show they are a Boolean algebra is to create complements.

As m is square free, an element a is a product of distinct primes.
Show a', the complement of a, is the product all the prime divisors of m that do not divide a.

Clearly the atoms are the primes.

Exercise.  If m is not square free, show that some elements do not have a complement.